# Test if externalptr object is null

Tags: r

How can I test from within R, without compiling custom C code, if an `externalptr` object is a null pointer? The best I can come up with is:

```
identical(capture.output(print(myptr)), "<pointer: 0x0>")
```

But that is kind of lame. I can do it in C, but I want to do it in R so that the user doesn't need a compiler.

Comment: i assume this doesn't quite do what you want http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26666614/how-do-i-check-if-an-externalptr-is-null-from-within-r ?

Comment: Well that is the C solution indeed. I would like something that doesn't require compiling custom C code.